# Add board names to custom components eagle

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

I have created two custom components for use in eagle 9.5.2 premium. When I insert the components to a project there are no visible names in neither the schematic or the PCB design.

I just want visible names in my PCB design just like the default components have, R1, C4 etc.

I looked into 3 component making tutorials but I still have not figured it out.

How do I make the names of custom components visible in the PCB design?

Comment: Did you add ">NAME" into the symbol of the part? Same with ">VALUE". [Read this](https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/blog/library-basics-part-2-creating-first-symbol-autodesk-eagle/).

Comment: yes I added ">NAME" in layer 95 names. And I updates all libraries

Comment: So, did this work? Should I leave it as an answer or are you deleting your question?

Comment: No it did not work, unfortunately. I am still not seeing names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked one of my libraries. What you want to do is add a ">VALUE" to layer 96 Values, and ">NAME" to layer 95 Names in the symbol file. Do the same thing in the footprint file, but use tNames and tValues layers instead. When you insert the device into your schematic file, the >Name tag should use the prefix value you set in the device file in your library, located at the bottom right of the screen. The >Value should show whatever text is showing in the technology tab I think. Also be sure that those layers are currently set to visible in the schematic, PCB layout, and update libraries. Try adding a new copy of the part too, I did that once and it fixed my issue when I didn't have names showing up. Otherwise, maybe try uploading the library and having us take a look at the component.

Comment: At first it did not work for the existing component, but it did for a new component, so instead of replacing the component I kept searching. I had to do both in sch as brd this: 'restore position'. When I did that the names and values appeared. Thank you for your help